# SELECT statement syntax

Tags: vb.net, ms-access

I'm trying to create a system where there will be a form showing up to notify the user that the products that has a month left to be expired, and here's where I am,

```
    Dim dtdate As Date
    dtdate = Now

    Dim commanddText As String = "SELECT * FROM tblDrugs WHERE ExpiryDate - 30 <= @ExpiryDate"

    Dim commandd As OleDbCommand = New OleDbCommand(commanddText, connection)
    commandd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ExpiryDate", dtdate)

    Dim reader As OleDbDataReader = command.ExecuteReader
    ListView1.Items.Clear()
    If reader.HasRows Then 'When there's a product that satisfies the condition, I put them in a listbox
        While reader.Read
            Dim search() As String = {reader(1).ToString, reader(2).ToString, reader(3).ToString, reader(7).ToString}


            Dim DrugsRecord As ListViewItem = New ListViewItem(search)
            ListView1.Items.Add(DrugsRecord)


        End While
```

When I try to debug it there's nothing showing in my listview even though there should be.
I'm new to vb and I'm not sure if my syntax for "commanddtext" is right.

Comment: If you are not sure if the query / math is correct, simplify it and/or use the debugger as needed.  SELECT ... WHERE Expiry > DateTime.Todate.Date.AddDays(29) .  The ListView is supremely ill-suited for DB ops and typed data in general.  use the DataGridView and a DataSource.  Please read [ask] and take the [Tour]

Comment: MS access does not like @ for query parameters.  Try it without the @ (Of course you will need  a different name for your param, like `theExpiryDate`)

Comment: @tgolisch, OP says this is vb.net, should @ parameter work in vb.net?

Comment: It is fine to use "@" as a parameter prefix with an Access database but the names are only for the developers reference because the database still uses position only. That means that parameters are substituted into the SQL code in the order they are added, whether the names match or not.

Comment: As @Plutonix has suggested, the `WHERE` clause makes no sense. You can't subtract 30 from a `Date/Time` value in SQL. What does that even mean? You presumably intend the 30 to be a number of days but how is the database supposed to know that? How is the database to know that you don't mean years or minutes or any other time division?

Comment: I don't know about vb.net but VBA defaults to Day unit when doing arithmetic with dates. `Date()-30` executed today returns 2/7/2018. Works in a query as well.

Answer (score 0):

I've been able to solve my problem by changing the syntax.

```
    Dim dtdate As Date
        dtdate = Now.AddMonths(1).Date
 Dim commandText As String = "SELECT * FROM tblDrugs WHERE ExpiryDate < @ExpiryDatee"
Dim command As OleDbCommand = New OleDbCommand(commandText, connection)

command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ExpiryDatee", dtdate)
```

Thank you for your opinions...